# Resize UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, ipad-2

I am getting a black patch partially on screen. Its a UIView and this happens only when device is in landscape mode. In portrait, it works fine.

Actual screenshot on iPad 2:
(Check the black patch)
[image]

Here is my View Hierarchy in Xcode:
(Please check the UIView highlighted. It is the one which is not completely stretched to the device's width)
[image]

Being newbie in iOS development, I am not sure about where is it going wrong. Would this be because of wrong dimensions of **self.view** ?

This is how I am defining **self.view**

```
CGRect deviceDimensions = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:deviceDimensions];
```

I tried explicitly setting width (just for debugging) as follows:

```
CGRect deviceDimensions = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
deviceDimensions.size.width = 768;
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:deviceDimensions];
```

but still its showing same.

Device: iPad 2 - Screen size: 1024x768
 iOS 8.2
Xcode v6.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-Layout. It's a beast of a tool but it takes a couple of minutes to get the basics down. Select the view in IB, and add height and width constraints to your view, like so:
[image]

If you prefer code, Take a look at the autoresizingMask property:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation != UIInterfaceLandscape) {
[view.superview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    return YES;
   }
}
```